# Solve for x in the following equation

Tags: exponential-function

We have $$4^x  + 6^x = 9^x$$

I simplified a bit and got the answer to be something like :

We have

$$\begin{align}{(2^2)}^x + 2^x 3^x &= (3^2)^x\\
\frac{{(2^2)}^x}{{(3^2)}^x} + \frac{2^x}{3^x} &= 1\end{align}$$
So,

$$\frac{2^x}{3^x} = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Thus

$$x = \frac{\log\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{ \log\frac{2}{3}}$$

Simplifying,
$$x = \frac{{\log(\sqrt{5}-1)}- {\log2}}{{\log2}-{\log3}}$$
Am I right or something is wrong?

Comment: Actually,  $\frac{2^x}{3^x} = \frac{-1 +\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%5Ex%2B6%5Ex%3D9%5Ex

Comment: Good deduction excepting that for the two possible values $\dfrac{2^x}{3^x} = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ you can take just what Alex Silva said above ($-1$ instead of $1$).

Comment: Because there's no way to get (2/3)^x=negative